# Exclude one fixed variable in "for" loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have for example 1 response variable, `Y` and 5 predictors, `X1-X5`.
I am trying to fit a glm model and calculating the deviance difference with `X5` fixed in the model as follows

```
ind_var <- names(dat)[substr(names(dat),1,1)=="X"]
results <- data.frame()
for (i in ind_var)
{
glm1 <- glm(as.formula(paste("Y~X5+",i)), family=binomial, data=dat)
dDeviance <- with(glm1,(null.deviance-deviance))
df <- data.frame(ind_var=i, diff=dDeviance)
results <- rbind(results, df)
}
```

Question :

1) How to exclude `X5` when the loop is selecting `i`

2) How to insert fixed variable in the model (here is `X5`). I noticed that when I paste `X5` in the model like above, the result is incorrect. Here, I do it manually to check the model with paste function, you can see that there is only 1 coefficient with 99 `df`. I believe in normal model with `Y~X5+X1` I should have 3 coefficients (including intercept) with 97 `df`.

```
mod1 <- glm(as.formula(paste("Y~X5+",X1)), family=binomial, data=dat)
mod1 

Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(paste("Y~X5+", X1)), family = binomial, 
data = dat)

Coefficients:
 X5  
0.02581  

Degrees of Freedom: 100 Total (i.e. Null);  99 Residual
Null Deviance:      138.6 
Residual Deviance: 138.6        AIC: 140.6
```

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not fully clear to me. Is `ind_var` a variable that contains the variable names? If so, to answer question 1, couldn't you solve this by removing `X5` from the vector? For question 2, why exactly is it wrong? Could you show the results and the expected results here?

Comment: Thanks @Laterow for your comments. I added some information in my previous post. About the ind_var, I need to actually repeat this with other variable as well (others X1/X2/X3/X4 as fixed variable). But, if I couldn't find the solution I will just have to delete it manually then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about adding `if` condition at the beginning of the `for loop`?

```
for(i in 1:10){
    if(i == 5) next

    print(i)
}
```

This skips to next `i` if `i == 5`.

In your case replace it with `X5`

**Alternatively**, why not use:

```
ind_var <- 1:10

for(i in ind_var[-5]){
            print(i)
        }
```